# StrictTemplates and union type in Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have this interface

```
export interface User{
  name: string
  birthday: number | Timestamp
  ...
}
```

with **strictTemplates:false** I use this interface when I get server data with birthday in Timestamp and when I put data in local Store with birthday in number. No errors.
In **strictTemplates: true** I have this error:

```
Types of property 'birthday' are incompatible.
Type 'number | Timestamp' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'Timestamp' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

What's the best practices here? I have made three interfaces:

```
 //without birthday
export interface User{
  name: string
  ...
}

export interface UserFromFirestore extends User {
  birthday: Timestamp;
}
export interface UserInLocal extends User {
  birthday: number;
}
```

And my function (in pseudo-code) is:

```
getUser(id: string):Observable<UserInLocal>{
  this.getDataFromFirestore(id).pipe(
  map((user:UserFromFirestore) => userWithBirthdayInNumber(user)))
}
```

I can do better right? My solution is too verbose right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics here.
more info : [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
export interface User<T>{
  name: string
  birthday: T
}

  obj1: User<number>;
  obj2: User<Timestamp>;
```